# MATLAB not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab

I keep trying to run this and have no idea what is going wrong. I have it saved as test.m. I click run in the editor and in the matlab command window, it states not enough input arguments. I feel like I am missing something totally obvious, but I cannot spot the issue.

```
function y = test(A, x)
    %This function computes the product of matrix A by vector x row-wise
    % define m number of rows here to feed into for loop
    [ma,na] = size(A);
    [mx,nx] = size(x);
    % use if statement to check for proper dimensions
    if(na == mx && nx == 1)
        y = zeros(ma,1);   % initialize y vector 
        for n = 1:ma
            y(n) = A(n,:)*x;
        end
    else
       disp('Dimensions of matrices do not match')
       y = [];
    end
end
```

Comment: You can't hit "run" because it takes arguments ("A" and "x"). You need to type `test(A,x)`, where you've hopefully defined some matrices `A` and `x`.

Comment: the question doesn't need linear-algebra tag.

Answer (score 8):

It is a function (not an script) and it needs some input arguments to run (in this case `A` and `x`), so you cannot hit the run button and expect it to run.

## The first way:

Instead you can use the command windows in MATLAB and enter the command:

```
A = rand(3,3); % define A here
x = ones(3,1); % define x here
test(A,x) % then run the function with its arguments
```

remember that `A` and `x` should be defined properly.

## The second way is:

Also you can hit the little triangle besides the green run button (see the figure below), and it will show you another option, `type command to run`. And 
there you can directly enter the same command `test(A,x)`. After that, each time you just hit enter for this function and it runs this command instead of only the `test` command without any argument.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## The third way:

```
function y = test(A, x)
%// TESTING CODE:
if nargin==0
    A = default_value_for_A;
    x = default_value_for_x;
end
... %// rest of the function code
```

This way allows you to "click the play button" and have your function run with no explicit input arguments. However, be advised that such a method should only be used:

- When **debugging**, so as not to allow users to call the function with no arguments if this is not its intended use case.
- If your function is not supposed to behave differently for a different number of inputs. See also [function overloading in MATLAB based on number of input arguments](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/01/08/advanced-matlab-varargin-and-nargin-variable-inputs-to-a-function/).