# Error when opening script in Matlab R2020a

Tags: matlab

I try to use a Matlab script written by someone else in my reasearch group a couple of years ago. This person is not in the group anymore.

If I open the script (double click on it on Windows Explorer), Matlab starts and before even running the script or doing anything else I immediately get these 5 error messages (as pop-up windows, not as an output in the console):

```
Error using matlab.internal.editor.OutputPackager
Error: File: OutputPackager.p Line: 63 Column: 0
The import statement 'import.matlab.internal.editor.StdoutOutputPackager' cannot be found or cannot be imported. Imported names must end with '.*' or be fully qualified.

Unrecognized function or variable 'matlab.internal.addons.updates.getSupportPackageUpdates'.

Unrecognized function or variable 'matlab.internal.addons.updates.getSupportPackageUpdates'.

Unrecognized function or variable 'matlab.unittest.internal.ui.toolstrip.getFileInfoForToolstrip'.

Unrecognized function or variable 'matlab.unittest.internal.ui.toolstrip.getFileInfoForToolstrip'.
```

I use Windows 10, 64 bit and Matlab R2020a Update 5.

Unfortunately, I cannot upload the file here and I am not able to produce a reproducible example (all my other files open normally). I also tried restarting Matlab and restarting my computer.

Comment: It looks like your former colleague used undocumented functions. Those are undocumented for a reason, since they can be changed by The MathWorks at any time without notice or reason. Either rewrite the function to work in 2020a, or run it using the MATLAB version your colleague wrote this in.

Comment: @Adriaan But does this already lead to error messages when opening the script? Should this not only be a problem when running the script? And also, is there a possiblility to identify, which of the functions are the undocumented ones? Because the error messages are not helpful here.

Comment: It's a P-file, which is obfuscated. This means that finding out which function it is is going to be very difficult. Probably by clicking a script in the file browser, which then launches MATLAB, the script automatically starts running (at least that's what I presume, I always launch MATLAB itself before loading scripts). I think the script *is* running, because otherwise it wouldn't throw an error within a specific script. You can check this by launching MATLAB itself first and then calling the script

Comment: If I start Matlab first, then open the script from there, then no error pops up. If I then run the script, I get a "normal" error message in the console `Not enough input arguments.`. So yes, it seems to do something different when doing a double click on the file in Windows explorer and when opening Matlab first and then opening the script in there.

Comment: That's  as I suspected for opening MATLAB first. Clicking a MATLAB file opens MATLAB and immediately runs the file. As to your error, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21862327). What you have is a function, which requires input arguments, not a script.