# Writing a MATLAB function for sinc(x)=sin(x)/x

Tags: function, matlab

I am trying to write a MATLAB function to evaluate sinc(x)=sin(x)/x over the interval [0,pi].
I have included my code below. It is saved as the file sinc3.m.

```
function y = sinc3(x)
if x<0
   disp('Outside specified interval of x');
   y=0;
elseif ((x>=0) && (x<=pi))
    sinc=@(x) sin(x)/x;
    y=sinc(x);
else
    disp('Outside specified interval of x');
   y=0;
end 
end
```

The error message "sinc3 requires more input arguments to run" is displayed. I do not understand what this means.

Comment: How are you running your function? You have to call it with an input argument: `sinc3(1)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I see. When I input values various of x the value of sinc3 is correct. However, when I run the script, the error "not enough input arguments" is displayed. Does this matter?

Comment: It is not a script, it is a function. You cannot run it as a script because it requires an input argument. Are you pressing the “run” button in the editor? You can configure that to call your function with an argument.

Comment: I see. This is my mistake; I have confused a script with a function. Yes, I have been pressing "run".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MATLAB not enough input arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862327/matlab-not-enough-input-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sinc Function for a Single Scalar:

Some adjustments for the function to run for a scalar input include setting the output `y` to zeros for the trivial cases that are outside the interval. This has to be done since the function is expected the output to be initialized and returned. Also, the if-statement do not require semi-colons in MATLAB at the end of them.

```
disp(sinc3(2));

function y = sinc3(x)
if x < 0
   disp('Outside specified interval of x');
  y = 0;

elseif ((x>=0) && (x<=pi))
    sinc= @(x) sin(x)/x;
    y =sinc(x);
    
else
   disp('Outside specified interval of x');
   y = 0;
   
end 
end
```

---

Using MATLAB's vectorized operations can greatly reduce the necessity of writing intricate loops. Below are two examples of evaluating and plotting a truncated sinc signal.

### Plotting Sinc Symbolically/Anonymous Functions:

This method uses a logical array named `Range` to truncate the sinc and constrain the signal within the range **[0,π]**. `Range` will only be true "1" where the parameter `x` is greater than 0 and less than π.  Everywhere else `Range` is false "0". By element-wise multiplying the `sin(x)./x` the sinc by `Range` the signal is truncated. This process can be visualized as multiplying a rectangular pulse that's only positive and exists within the range by the sinc.

[image: Symbolically Evaluating Function]

```
%Plotting the sinc symbolically%
syms x
Range = ((x >= 0) & (x <= pi));
sinc = @(x) (sin(x)./x).*Range;
fplot(sinc(x));
```

---

### For Evaluating Specific Values/Vectors:

To evaluate specific values we can neglect declaring `x` as a symbolic variable and instead pass a vector as input into the anonymous function.

[image: Anonymous Function With Vector Inputs]

```
%Generating a vector of x-values to evaluate the sinc for%
Start_Time = 0; End_Time = 20;
Interval = 0.1;
X = (0:Interval:20);

Sinc_Signal = @(x) (sin(x)./x).*((x >= 0) & (x <= pi));
plot(X,Sinc_Signal(X),'Marker','.');
xlim([-5 5]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. Your first example works great. However, I am specifically trying to write a MATLAB function file of a form similar to that in my original question.

Comment: No problem, I'll try to add something that is more similar to what you had as well.

Comment: May I ask is your input `x` going to be a vector?

Comment: I do not believe so. I think it is simply a scalar.

Comment: Alright added it to the top of my answer. Is that roughly what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but I am still getting the same error message. I have included my updated code in my original question.

Comment: Works for me. Is your function defined locally or in another `.m` file? If it's locally ensure it's a the bottom of the script.

Comment: Possibly you have another function named `sinc3()`?

Comment: It is defined in a separate `.m` file. Can the command `fplot` be used to plot the function on the doman `[0,pi]`?

Comment: Since it's only a singular value you could use `plot()`.